# Formatting output in summarise_each with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Greetings:  I am new to dplyr and having some challenges formatting my output.  Here is a code snippet that produces some reproducible data, using `melt` to get it into the shape I need.

```
set.seed(1234)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
val <- c(0:1)
a <- sample(val, 99, replace=T)
b <- sample(val, 99, replace=T)
c <- sample(val, 99, replace=T)
d <- sample(val, 99, replace=T)
dat <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
melt.dat <- melt(dat)
```

Now, I can perform the desired summary:

```
SummaryTable <- melt.dat %>%
group_by(variable) %>%
summarise_each(funs(sum, sum/n()))
```

Here is my output:

```
  variable sum        *
1        a  50 50.50505
2        b  58 58.58586
3        c  46 46.46465
4        d  46 46.46465
```

My ideal output would be something as follows.  I am unable able to figure out how to specify my column names in the `summarise_each` or `melt` functions, set the decimal place and suppress the row numbers.  I've spent a long time getting this far, and just can't seem to get the rest figured out!

```
   Letter Count Percent
        a    50    50.5
        b    58    58.6
        c    46    46.5
        d    46    46.5
```

Comment: My bad -- it should have said "unable."  Question has been edited.

Comment: Do you care about the row names because you want to save it to a csv file or similar? (If yes, you can easily specify not to include row names in the file)

Comment: To print without row names, try `print.data.frame(data, row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: Actually, `print(data, row.names = FALSE)` should do it because it will dispatch to `print.data.frame`

Comment: @RichardScriven, `print(data, row.names = FALSE)` doesn't seem to work as you hypothesized for a `tbl_df` object - maybe because there's also a `print.tbl_df` which is used here? But, `print.data.frame(data, row.names = FALSE)` does work.

Comment: @beginneR , right you are.  You'd need to reverse the classes for `print` to dispatch to `print.data.frame` in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure whether it's possible within dplyr to suppress rownames (numbering), but here's how you could get the names and formatting right:

```
options(digits = 3)

melt.dat %>%
  group_by(Letter = variable) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(Count = sum(.), Percent = sum(.)/n()*100), -variable)

#Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
#
#  Letter Count Percent
#1      a    45    45.5
#2      b    51    51.5
#3      c    52    52.5
#4      d    48    48.5
```

Comment: Aha!! It's `print.data.frame(dat, row.names = FALSE)`